# Ignore everything between /* and */ regex (regexr.com)

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically I am trying to select everything except things between /* */
Just like a c++ compiler doesn't read what's between those running.

I have come so far which sort of works but it begins the ignoring already when a * is places
And if it doesn't get a */ it will select everything except /*

So everything from /* to */ should be ignore. If */ is missed then it should not select anything from the beginning of  /*

`\[^\*\/\*\/]+(?![^(\/\*)]*(\*).)\g`

I hope it makes sense

I am using regexr.com to build my regex

Comment: you should **know** which language you're using, not **think you know**.

Comment: just remove `/* */` and everything in between http://jsfiddle.net/9wLzn3c0/

Comment: `/\/\*(.*?)\*\/g` would be the lazy variant

Comment: @Ja͢ck then it should be `\/\*(.*?)+\*\//g`, but that selects it and I need the opposite

Comment: Wouldn't you get the opposite simply by replacing all occurrences of commented out segments by nothing?

Comment: Well, maybe I am not clear enough hehe. I want to select everything that is not a "comment", so: "this will `/*ignored*/` be selected"

Comment: Ah, that ... you need a much more comprehensive solution (read parser).

Comment: Regexps don't "select", they "match". They are often part of a process of matching and replacing. Matching all the things you don't want, and replacing them with an empty string, is entirely equivalent to matching all the things you want and keeping them. It's not clear to me why you care whether your regexp matches comments, or matches non-comment portions. In this case, it's very hard if not impossible to write a regexp which matches all the parts of a string **except** those which match some pattern. It's much easier, and more natural, to match each part you don't want, and kill it.

Comment: It makes sense. Post an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newstring= oldstring.split(/\/\*([^\*]|\*[^\/])+\*\//).join('');
```